# How do I use the alarm every Monday?

Tags: nsdate, uilocalnotification

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

[nowComponents setWeekday:2]; //Monday
[nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week] + 1]; //Next week
[nowComponents setHour:8]; //8a.m.
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];

NSDate *timeDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];



localNotif.fireDate = timeDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;


localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nowtime %@ == %@ %@ %@ %@ ",date,saveDataWeekday,saveDataAmPm,saveDataHour,saveDataMinute];

localNotif.alertAction = @"info";
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Alarm does not work on a specified day of the week

I want to setting 
for example 
-> Every monday or Every friday or Every day

Comment: What are some examples of the values you get when you print the timeDate?

Comment: Every Sunday,
Every Monday,
Every Tuesday,
Every Wednesday,
Every Thursday,
Every Friday,
Every Saturday,
Every DAY, For example -> Every Sunday AM 9:00 , Every Monday PM 5:00